# Compiling libDispatch (GCD) for Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, libdispatch

I'm trying to compile [libdispatch for linux](https://github.com/PSPDFKit-labs/libdispatch) on Android. However I could not find any instructions for Android in the project files.

I can see there are [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34924507/libdispatch-serving-runonmainqueuedelayed-from-java) StackOverflow [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18916567/libdispatch-serving-main-queue-without-dispatch-main-on-android) about using libdispatch, but the information is rather thin.

Has anyone successfully compiled **libdispatch** for Android using NDK?

Comment: If anyone is having the same issue, here's what worked for me:

`ndk-build NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=clang NDK_PROJECT_PATH=libdispatch/ APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=libdispatch/Android.mk`

Comment: For anyone finding this later, the command Sam posted worked for me, but only after also cloning github.com/mackyle/blocksruntime github.com/PSPDFKit-labs/libkqueue and github.com/PSPDFKit-labs/libpthread_workqueue into the same directory libdispatch is in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't personally tried compiling libdispatch for Android, but I have built many other libraries. It looks like building libdispatch should be quite easy, as there is already an [Android.mk](https://github.com/PSPDFKit-labs/libdispatch/blob/71197ddf37eec43ba4455ffadfba18c8d462ac6c/Android.mk) file in the repository. You should be able to build this library with the following command (split across lines for readability):

```
<ndk directory path>/ndk-build \ 
-C <path to libdispatch source directory> \
NDK_LIBS_OUT=<path to directory for built libraries> \
APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=Android.mk
```

Comment: I've tried that earlier and it gave me error:

`Android NDK: Could not find application project directory !`
`Android NDK: Please define the NDK_PROJECT_PATH variable to point to it.`

Comment: Did you pass the path to your project directory to ndk-build using the -C argument? Some folks are using NDK_PROJECT_PATH= instead of -C to pass the project path, but I've never used that with newer NDKs. What version of the ndk are you using?

Comment: I'm trying to compile and build the libdispatch project checked out from Github.

Here's the error I get now:

`ndk-build NDK_PROJECT_PATH=./libdispatch`
`Android NDK: Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: ./libdispatch/jni/Android.mk`
`/Users/sam/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/build/core/add-application.mk:195: *** Android NDK: Aborting....Stop.`


Do I need to include the libdispatch as a submodule in an Android project? I'm totally lost :-(

Comment: The expectation is that the Android.mk file is always inside a directory named jni, so ndk-build is attempting to find the path jni/Android.mk inside the libdispatch directory. It doesn't exist, hence the error. This is a mistake on the part of the libdispatch developers, IMO. Try adding APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=<path to libdispatch directory>/Android.mk to your ndk-build command.

Comment: Actually, use APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=Android.mk to your ndk-build command. APP_BUILD_SCRIPT is relative to the directory specified with    -C.

Comment: Thanks, I figured that out from the source and got past it. There are some compile errors due to blocksruntime. The 3 projects mentioned in the README have no instructions to compile and I'll have to ask the maintainer on the GitHub repo.

Comment: Here's the error BTW:


`ndk-build NDK_PROJECT_PATH=libdispatch/ APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=libdispatch/Android.mk                                0 < 15:11:30
[armeabi] Compile thumb  : dispatch <= apply.c
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-momit-leaf-frame-pointer'
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-fblocks'
make: *** [libdispatch//obj/local/armeabi/objs/dispatch/src/apply.o] Error 1`

Comment: I think you should accept my answer, in that case. BTW, that error probably means you should be using the Clang toolchain, not GCC.

Comment: Using clang solved the issue, Thanks a lot, I'll accept your answer :-)